# Macros can't return anonymous functions? Clojure

Tags: clojure, macros

I have the following macro:

```
(defmacro anon-mac [value]
  #(+ value 1))
```

I would expect for this to behave as such:

```
((anon-mac 1) 1) ;=> 2
```

However I get this error:

```
IllegalArgumentException No matching ctor found for class user$anon_mac$fn__10767  clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeConstructor (Reflector.java:163)
```

What should I do to be able to have this macro return an anonymous function that works as I would expect?

**The answer must be a macro.** Seeing as my question concerns the ability of *macros* to return anonymous functions

**Why must the answer be a macro?** In my case it is because I do not want this conversion to be called more than once at compile time wherever it is found. If I were to have this conversion in a for loop that called it 200 times, with a function the conversion would be run 200 times. However seeing as macros edit the code itself it would only be run once for that for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I simply needed to escape the function while evaluating the inner variable like so:

```
(defmacro anon-mac [value] `#(+ % ~value))
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you are using it for, but if you wanted to go with a function, you might find [partial](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/partial) helpful, as it provides the behavior that you are after.

```
(defn anon-partial [val] (partial + val))
((anon-partial 1) 1) ;;=> 2
```

There are also some helpful examples of `partial` at [clojuredocs.org](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/partial).

Comment: This is true. My particular case is more complex than the example I provided and requires interpretation at compile time. Thanks!

Comment: @JasonBasanese, please state the actual problem you are trying to solve in clear and simple terms.  It does not do anyone any good if you simply say "my particular case is more complex".  If it's more complex, then your question should be more complex.  You'll get much better answers that way, since we won't have to guess at what the end goal is.

Comment: My apologies for the confusion. I will clarify my question to include that not using a macro is not an option.

Comment: @JasonBasanese, no, that does *not* provide any clarity at all.  You said that "My particular case is more complex that the example I provided".  In what ways is it more complex?  In other words, **what haven't you told us?**

Comment: Seeing as I you are curious, I added why.